# Schwarz inequality for unital positive maps on C*-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, conjectures

I was recently studying [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266539707_Some_assorted_inequalities_for_positive_linear_maps_on_C-algebras) paper by Man-Duen Choi about inequalities for positive maps on C*-algebras. He demonstrates that

> Let $\phi : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ be a unital positive linear map between the two C*-algebras $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$. Then
>
> $$
> \phi(A^* A) \ge \phi(A)^* \, \phi(A)
> $$
>   and
>
> $$
> \phi(A^* A) \ge \phi(A) \, \phi(A)^*
> $$
>
> for  every subnormal $A \in \mathcal{A}$.

He then conjectures that the same result might apply also for *hyponormal* opertators, i.e. operators such that $A^* A \ge A A^*$ (this conjecture is equivalent to the Woronowicz's conjecture).

I was wondering whether this conjecture has been better investigated or not. Also, is there a characterization of hyponormal operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll to the bottom of the PDF (e.g. the one in https://www.jstor.org/stable/24714007 ), it says:

> Added in proofs. E. Kirchberg has recently shown by a non-constructive
> proof that there  exists a counter-example to Woronowicz's Conjecture.
> Hence, Conjecture 3.4 is also false  by virtue of Proposition 3

So, the conjecture is false.